# xpath to find href link content

Tags: xpath, hpple

```
<td class="subject" id="td_111111">
<a href="thread-htm-fid-75-type-333.html" class="f14 view">[health]</a>
<a href="the link I want" name="readlink" 
 id="a_ajax_880700" class="subject_t f14"><b><font color=#FF0000>how to make this show</font></b></a>&nbsp;
```

how to grab href location in above "the link I want" by Xpath? not only one part need to parse

I used below to parse,but fail
:@"//a[@class='subject_t f14']/@href"

Answer (score 0):

You've tried this?

```
"//a[@id='a_ajax_880700']//@href"
```

Comment: You need `"//a[@id='a_ajax_880700']/@href"`

Comment: no,it didn't work yet,thanks for ur opinion, I try other post and use loop to get all elements in xpath result,just like     [[element attributes] objectForKey:@"href"]